# Mongoose query is not promises but we could use await without exec()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m using mongoose that could use await when we are not using exec() at the end of function.
*Sorry for my bad english

```
async function myFn(){
     const user1 = await User.findOne({..});
     const user2 = await User.findOne({..}).exec();
};
```

Why User.findOne treated like a promise even though without using exec function?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose queries can be `await`ed for convenience.

From a section of the mongoose docs titled [Queries are Not Promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises):

> Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a `.then()` function for [co](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) and [async/await](http://thecodebarbarian.com/common-async-await-design-patterns-in-node.js.html) as a convenience.